# Cisco SG500x-24P - Discard untagged

Tags: cisco, vlan, security

Cisco SG500X-24P Switch.

### Goal

Only admin tagged frames, discard untagged frames (ingress & egress)

### Question

Is the following configuration correct:

Port VLAN Mode: **General**
VLANs: **100T, 200T, 4095P**
Ingress filtering **enabled**
**Admit Tagged Only**

Is there anything else that I should configure to discard untagged traffic?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `P` indicates untagged traffic will be placed on that VLAN. 4095 is usually the VLAN for discarded traffic.